# Remove duplicated letters except in abbreviations

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'd like to remove duplicated letters from a string as long as there are more letters. For instance, consider the following list:

```
aaa --> it is untouched because all are the same letters
aa  --> it is untouched because all are the same letters
a   --> not touched, just one letter
broom --> brom
school --> schol
boo --> should be bo
gool --> gol
ooow  --> should be ow
```

I use the following regex to get rid of the duplicates as follows:

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z])\1+(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

However, this is failing in the string `boo` which is kept as the original `boo` instead of removing the double o. The same happens with `oow` which is not reduced to `ow`.

Do you know why `boo` is not taken by the regex?

Comment: What should the output be for respectively `gogol`, `gogool`, `googol` and `googool`?

Comment: should be gogol all of them. The duplicates just apply to one letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match and capture whole words consisting of identical chars into one capturing group, and then match repetitive consecutive letters in all other contexts, and replace accordingly:

```py
import re
text = "aaa, aa, a,broom, school...boo, gool, ooow."
print( re.sub(r'\b(([a-zA-Z])\2+)\b|([a-zA-Z])\3+', r'\1\3', text) )
# => aaa, aa, a,brom, schol...bo, gol, ow.
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/CgJACp) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vqrbFW/1).

**Regex details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(([a-zA-Z])\2+)` - Group 1: an ASCII letter (captured into Group 2) and then one or more occurrences of the same letter
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `|` - or
- `([a-zA-Z])` - Group 3: an ASCII letter captured into Group 3
- `\3+` - one or more occurrences of the letter captured in Group 3.

The replacement is a concatenation of Group 1 and Group 3 values.

To match any Unicode letters, replace `[a-zA-Z]` with `[^\W\d_]`.

Answer (score 1):

You regular expression dosen't match boo because it searches for a duplicate that has at least one different character both before and after.

One possibility is to make a simpler regex to catch all duplicates and then revert if the result is one character

```
def remove_duplicate(string):
    new_string = re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z])\1+', r'\1', string)
    return new_string if len(new_string) > 1 else string
```

Here is a possible solution without regular expression. It's faster but it will remove duplicates of white space and punctuation too. Not only letters.

```
def remove_duplicate(string):
    new_string = ''
    last_c = None
    for c in string:
        if c == last_c:
            continue
        else:
            new_string += c
            last_c = c
    if len(new_string) > 1:
        return new_string
    else:
        return string
```